# Is there a way to keep rigid body properties on object after baking physics animation to frames?

Tags: baking

I bake an objects physics rigid body animation to frames and then the rigid body properties for that object are removed.  Is there a way to keep them?  I understand that since the object is now keyframed that those properties are useless for the frame range that was baked, but what if I want to use the object in more physics later on (or would that be something you just don't do?) ?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'll clarify my question a little more.  I know that I can now put rigid body back on the object, but I want all the same settings back on the body - is there a way to retain or regain the original settings when putting the rigid body back on?

Comment: Retaining physics settings once removed aren't recoverable as far as I'm aware. As your question has changed some, my original comment/suggestion would no longer be correct and has been deleted.